# unable to access function from another function using this within same object

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following:

```
  $scope.option = {
        generateID:function(){
            return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5);
        },

        values : [
            {id:this.generateId()},
            {id:this.generateId()},
            {id:this.generateId()},
            {id:this.generateId()}
        ],
        markCorrect : function(option){

        },

        remove:function(option)
        {

            this.values = this.values.filter(function(value){return value.id!=option.id})
        }
    }
```

I always get a `this.generateId is not a function` error. I am pretty sure that i am missing something fundamental here!

Comment: `this` is referring to the object that contains `id` instead of the `option` object. You notice those are objects in the `values` array right? Those are the objects `this` is referring to.

Comment: {id:$scope.option.generateId()} doesn't work as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be better to store the id generator function in a separate function so it is easier to reference:

```
 function generateId = function() {
     return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5);
 }
 $scope.option = {
        generateID: generateId,

        values : [
            {id: generateId()},
            {id: generateId()},
            {id: generateId()},
            {id: generateId()}
        ],
        markCorrect : function(option){

        },

        remove:function(option)
        {

            this.values = this.values.filter(function(value){return value.id!=option.id})
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of the line `generateID: generateId,` if you're going to use the global `generateId` function in `values` anyway?

Comment: @Sam Perhaps consumers of $scope.option would like to use it's generator function? Other than that, I would remove the generateID member

Comment: Looks clean and resuable!

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that you're trying to access properties of `$scope.option` in the middle of declaring it. Try doing something like this instead:

```
$scope.option = (function () {
  function generateId () {
    /* logic */
  }

  return {
    values: [
      {id: generateId()}
      // ...
    ],
    markCorrect: function () {},
    remove: function () {}
  };

}) ();
```

This is the 'revealing module pattern', i.e. a function that returns an object forming a closure on some other data or functionality.

Comment: Exactly the explanation i was looking for !! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo; rename `generateID` to `generateId`.